# Tax rate on cart page

Tags: cart, tax

I need to display the tax rate (varies with different countries) next to shipping text on cart page. How could I print the tax rate used in template php file?

Comment: have you even tried googling it? [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=magento+tax+rate+shopping+cart&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:fr:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=Bp30U4iaGImB8Qfe94GIBg&gws_rd=cr) it is for you ;)

Comment: Well that was not what I was looking for. I need the rate printed in cart and checkout (20% in text for EU citizens and 0% for everybody else). In my template there is no way to get those rates in text visible so I need the PHP code that could print them for me.

Not the calculated tax in euros but the percentage as text like this:
Tax (20%): xx,xx €

Comment: get your customer's tax rate (which is given by it's country if you've orgenized your taxes correctly), and then take a look at `getRate()` method for model 'tax/calculation'

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly you want to highlight what taxes are applied on cart totals.

What configuration did you have setup System>Configuration>Sales>Tax

Shopping Cart Display Settings and option:

Include Tax In Grand Total  [STORE VIEW] **Yes** 
Display Full Tax Summary    [STORE VIEW] **Yes** 

The name that's being displayed in frontend cart totals, are in Sales>Tax>Manage Tax Zone & Rates, then you edit the rate and at the bottom there are Tax Titles for each Store View.

If i understand you in a bad way - then do you want to display tax rate for shipping cost on estimated shipping cost block?

### EDIT: Shipping cost tax percentage on cart page

This is kind of a hack, but I think you'll get an idea behind it and you can do whatever you want with it.

Go to /template/checkout/cart/shipping_method/available.html

Find around line ~59:

```
<?php $_excl = $this->getShippingPrice($_rate->getPrice(), $this->helper('tax')->displayShippingPriceIncludingTax()); ?>
<?php $_incl = $this->getShippingPrice($_rate->getPrice(), true); ?>
```

Above you can see how's shipping method cost is displayed on frontend. Try to add for testing purposes code like this:

```
<?php echo $excluding = (float)preg_replace('/\D/', '', $_excl)/100; ?>         
<?php echo $including = (float)preg_replace('/\D/', '', $_incl)/100; ?>         
<?php $taxamount=$including-$excluding;
      $taxPercentage = ($taxamount / 100) * $including;
      $percent = $taxamount/$excluding;
      echo $percent_friendly = number_format( $percent * 100, 2 ) . '%';
?>
```

Now above the variable $excluding gets estimated shipping cost without tax amount and converts it to float number format. Same goes for $including.

Then we subtract $excluding from $including and we have variable $taxamount which's the tax amount in number format. The rest is obvious I think.

I hope you'll find a better way to implement this solution – it's simplest, baddest hack in template file.

Comment: I need to show the tax percentage of the shipping like this: Delivery (incl. tax 24%): €100. (Note that I mean the percentage in numbers, not the sum in euros).

Comment: Edited my answer with more specific answer. Check it out.